# Can't print to pdf ggplot charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate multiple graphics from within an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547306/generate-multiple-graphics-from-within-an-r-function)

Very strange thing happening to me: the following code fails to print to pdf device:

```
outnames <- c("1.pdf", "2.pdf")
for (n in outnames){
    pdf(n)
    qplot(1:10)
    dev.off()
}
```

won't print anything to pdf, even though a pdf file is generated. However,

```
pdf(outnames[2])
qplot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

will work perfectly well. Any idea why? Reproduced in R 2.11.1.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Gappy, that smells like the [FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f) -- so please try `print(qplot(1:10))`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm amazed how counterintuitive R sometimes^Woften is. I must say that the `ggsave` approach below makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 13):

@Dirk explains why this is happening (auto printing turned off), but an alternative to opening the device, generating the plot on the device, closing the device is `ggsave()`. For example:

```
p1 <- qplot(1:10)
ggsave("p1.pdf", plot = p1)
```

or via a loop:

```
outnames <- c("1.pdf", "2.pdf")
for (n in outnames){
    p2 <- qplot(1:10)
    ggsave(n, plot = p2)
}
```

At the end of that we have all the generated plots we asked for.

```
> list.files(pattern = ".pdf$")
[1] "1.pdf"                  "2.pdf"                 
[3] "p1.pdf"
```

Comment: Actually his loop works fine, because he's not indexing into `outnames`, he's just using the value.  It's the way I would do it too.

Comment: Well spotted @Ken that was my own stupidity attached to @Gappy --- will delete the noise!

Comment: @Ken hmm something seems to be stopping me from accepting your edits. and then I can't edit the post now either...

Comment: @Shog9 has now approved the edit for me (after posting on meta about the problem).

Comment: How can you do this but saving all plots to the same file, as `par(mfrow)` does?