# Associating significance values to different df in a list using a for loop

Tags: r

I have the following column names (long format)
df name: df.tidy.1

```
"Sample_ID"                           "group_classification"               
"Days_after_infection_1"              "category post-infection or 1st dose"
"p.i. category#"                      "category post-1st dose"             
"post 1st dose category#"             "category post-2nd dose"             
"post 2nd dose category#"             "abs"                                
"titers"                              "control_classification"
```

I want to perform a statistical analysis using the Kruskal and Dunn test. The main idea is to perform a loop for each unique value in the column `abs`

```
abs <- unique(df.tidy.1$abs)

abs.plot.list <- list()
```

Then, I perform a for loop to create 10 plots (abs = 10 unique values). The code works when I use the Wilcox test, but I want to use Kruskal and Dunn instead to compare groups.
With this in mind, here is the main code:

```
for(i in seq_along(abs)) {
  # wilcox test
  df.stat <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
     filter(abs == abs[i]) %>%
     wilcox_test(titers ~ group_classification) %>% 
     add_xy_position(y.trans = log10)
   
  # df.kw.stat <- df.tidy.1 %>%
  #   group_by(group_classification) %>%
  #   filter(abs == abs[i]) %>%
  #   kruskal_test(titers ~ group_classification) %>%
  #   adjust_pvalue(p.col = 'p', method = 'BH') %>%
  #   arrange(p)
  # 
  # # Apply statistical test for multiple comparison groups
  # df.dunn.stat <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
  #   group_by(abs) %>%
  #   filter(abs == abs[i]) %>%
  #   dunn_test(titers ~ group_classification) %>% 
  #   add_y_position(scales = 'free_y')
  
  # Plot control data 
  control.df <- df.tidy.1 %>%
    filter(abs == abs[i],
           group_classification == 'Control')
  
  natural.hybrid <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
    filter(abs == abs[i], 
           group_classification %in% c('Natural', 
                                       'Hybrid'))
  
  induced <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
    filter(abs == abs[i], 
           group_classification == 'Induced')
  
  p <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
    filter(abs == abs[i]) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = group_classification, y = titers)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_jitter(data = natural.hybrid, shape = 21, width = 0.1, size = 2,
                aes(fill = `category post-infection or 1st dose`))+
    geom_jitter(data = induced, width = 0.1, 
                aes(color = `category post-1st dose`), size = 2) +
    geom_jitter(data = control.df, width = 0.1,
                aes(color = 'Control_classification'), size = 2) +
    scale_fill_viridis_d() +
    #scale_color_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, 'Dark2')[c(1,3)],) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, 'Dark2')[c(1,3)], 
                                  "black")) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10') +
    labs(x = '', y = 'Ab Titer (AU/ml)') +
    stat_pvalue_manual(df.stat, step.increase = 0.1, hide.ns = 'p',
                       label = 'p.adj.signif') +
    ggtitle(abs[i])
  
  abs.plot.list[[i]] <- p
}

names(abs.plot.list) <- abs
```

In the previous code, I commented on the lines related to the Kruskal and Dunn tests. The code generates 10 different plots when I use the Wilcox test. However, when I comment Wilcox test lines and put Kruskal and Dunn, I can generate two df with the information that I need, like this (Kruskal: 10 rows):

```
abs                              .y.        n statistic    df             p method                p.adj
  <chr>                            <chr>  <int>     <dbl> <int>         <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1 SARS_COV2_Nucleocapsid_IgG_AU_mL titers    89      41.5     3 0.00000000519 Kruskal-Wallis 0.0000000519
2 SARS_COV2_S1_NTD_IgG_AU_mL       titers    89      39.6     3 0.0000000128  Kruskal-Wallis 0.000000064 
3 SARS_COV2_Spike_IgG_AU_mL        titers    89      36.6     3 0.000000056   Kruskal-Wallis 0.000000168 
4 SARS_COV2_S1_RBD_IgG_AU_mL       titers    89      36.2     3 0.0000000674  Kruskal-Wallis 0.000000168 
5 SARS_COV1_Spike_IgG_AU_mL        titers    89      34.2     3 0.000000179   Kruskal-Wallis 0.000000358 
6 SARS_CoV2_S1_RBD_IgM_AU_mL       titers    89      17.2     3 0.000644      Kruskal-Wallis 0.00107
```

(Dunn: 60 rows):

```
abs            .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p   p.adj p.adj.signif y.position groups
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <name>
1 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Contr… Induc…    10    14     3.04  2.36e-3 7.08e-3 **              920138. <chr> 
2 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Contr… Natur…    10    38     3.34  8.43e-4 3.37e-3 **             1038104. <chr> 
3 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Contr… Hybrid    10    27     5.65  1.60e-8 9.58e-8 ****           1156071. <chr> 
4 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Induc… Natur…    14    38    -0.232 8.16e-1 8.16e-1 ns             1274037. <chr> 
5 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Induc… Hybrid    14    27     2.53  1.15e-2 2.29e-2 *              1392003. <chr> 
6 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Natur… Hybrid    38    27     3.60  3.22e-4 1.61e-3 **             1509970. <chr>
```

So, if I uncomment these lines, I got an unexpected behavior:

```
df.kw.stat <- df.tidy.1 %>%
     group_by(group_classification) %>%
     filter(abs == abs[i]) %>%
     kruskal_test(titers ~ group_classification) %>%
     adjust_pvalue(p.col = 'p', method = 'BH') %>%
     arrange(p)
   
  # # Apply statistical test for multiple comparison groups
   df.dunn.stat <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
     group_by(abs) %>%
     filter(abs == abs[i]) %>%
     dunn_test(titers ~ group_classification) %>% 
     add_y_position(scales = 'free_y')
```

The codes work, however, my result is wrong because all the plots are the same, and all the significant differences are put in one plot. So, I think that my issue is that R is unable to recognize where to put the significance values resulting from the Kruskal and Dunn tests.

What can I do to associate each value from the Statistical analysis to each plot in the for loop?

Comment: This is because ggplot is evaluating the data _lazily_, which means when it finally goes to plot, it looks in the calling environment for the object named `i` and finds its current value (which is the last of your loop). If instead you use `lapply` (as in the dupe-links, momentarily), when it finds its `i`, it'll be the correct one. In other words, replace `for (i in seq_along(..)) { ... }` with `plots <- lapply(seq_along(..), function(i) { ... })` and then plot each of the `plots`.

Comment: Don't vandalize your post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I can't find a good dupe-link, so in the mean-time here's an answer ...)

`grid`- and `ggplot2`-graphics operate in a more "lazy" fashion, not evaluating the data until it is actually rendered. Similar to [Generate multiple graphics from within an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2547306/3358272), [Can't print to pdf ggplot charts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811106/3358272), [ggplot does not work if it is inside a for loop although it works outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15678261/3358272), this "find the data for real" happens when it is actually printed/rendered, not when it is created.

One trick (and the one I see the most) is to replace the `for` loop with an `lapply`, mostly identical code.

```r
### for(i in seq_along(abs)) {                          # OLD
abs.plot.list <- lapply(seq_along(abs), function(i) {   # NEW
  # wilcox test
  df.stat <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
     filter(abs == abs[i]) %>%
     wilcox_test(titers ~ group_classification) %>% 
     add_xy_position(y.trans = log10)
   
  # df.kw.stat <- df.tidy.1 %>%
  #   group_by(group_classification) %>%
  #   filter(abs == abs[i]) %>%
  #   kruskal_test(titers ~ group_classification) %>%
  #   adjust_pvalue(p.col = 'p', method = 'BH') %>%
  #   arrange(p)
  # 
  # # Apply statistical test for multiple comparison groups
  # df.dunn.stat <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
  #   group_by(abs) %>%
  #   filter(abs == abs[i]) %>%
  #   dunn_test(titers ~ group_classification) %>% 
  #   add_y_position(scales = 'free_y')
  
  # Plot control data 
  control.df <- df.tidy.1 %>%
    filter(abs == abs[i],
           group_classification == 'Control')
  
  natural.hybrid <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
    filter(abs == abs[i], 
           group_classification %in% c('Natural', 
                                       'Hybrid'))
  
  induced <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
    filter(abs == abs[i], 
           group_classification == 'Induced')
  
  p <- df.tidy.1 %>% 
    filter(abs == abs[i]) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = group_classification, y = titers)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_jitter(data = natural.hybrid, shape = 21, width = 0.1, size = 2,
                aes(fill = `category post-infection or 1st dose`))+
    geom_jitter(data = induced, width = 0.1, 
                aes(color = `category post-1st dose`), size = 2) +
    geom_jitter(data = control.df, width = 0.1,
                aes(color = 'Control_classification'), size = 2) +
    scale_fill_viridis_d() +
    #scale_color_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, 'Dark2')[c(1,3)],) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, 'Dark2')[c(1,3)], 
                                  "black")) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10') +
    labs(x = '', y = 'Ab Titer (AU/ml)') +
    stat_pvalue_manual(df.stat, step.increase = 0.1, hide.ns = 'p',
                       label = 'p.adj.signif') +
    ggtitle(abs[i])

  #   abs.plot.list[[i]] <- p                           # OLD
  p                                                     # NEW
# }                                                     # OLD
})                                                      # NEW (just a paren)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, however, I still have the same result, I don't understand. Is it possible to create a chat session to share you the data?

Comment: I checked again, uncommented the lines of Kruskal and Dunn, and commented Wilcox test. I have the same results, all the plots are the same and all the statistical significances are in the same plot
I added an example to show you what I mean (new figure)

Comment: Okay, it was worth a shot. I can't reproduce your problem, so not sure what else I can do here.

Comment: my data is in long format, so I can put everything here. Is there a way to share that on a chat session in stack overflow?

Comment: Unfortunately not in a Stack chat. Other techniques I've seen (with pros/cons for each) include: (1) adapt to a built-in dataset in R; (2) publicly available dataset, e.g., `read.csv("https://.../somedata.csv")`; (3) google drive links; or (4) pastebin.com. The risk of the latter three are that the links go cold and the question becomes not-reproducible ... but those are all options.