# Why is ggplot not plotting multiple windows in R?

Tags: r, scope, ggplot2

I am having a problem with a couple R functions I wrote. I have 2 plotting functions and I want to write a function that creates plots for both of the functions. This function looks like this

```
 plotBoth = function(path = NULL){
     plotPopulationStats(path)
     plotInstructionFrequencies(path)
 }
```

However only whichever instruction I call second gets plotted, while the first instruction only plots a blank window. Below are simplified versions of these functions.

```
 plotInstructionFrequencies = function(path = NULL){
   quartz()
   table <- read.table(path, header=TRUE);
   frame <- as.data.frame(table);
   frame$time = seq(1, length(table$noop));
   frame$mean = NULL
   frame$sd = NULL
   frame$variance = NULL
   Molten <- melt(frame, id.vars = "time");
   ggplot(Molten, aes(x = time, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
}
```

and

```
plotPopulationStats = function(path = NULL){
    quartz()
    table <- read.table(path, header=TRUE);
    frame <- as.data.frame(table);
    frame$time = seq(1, length(table$noop));
    frame$noop = NULL
    frame$plus = NULL
        ...
    frame$store = NULL
        Molten <- melt(frame, id.vars = "time");
    ggplot(Molten, aes(x = time, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line();
}
```

All the functions are in separate files, but I would like to have them all in one file.

Both functions plot fine when called individually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate multiple graphics from within an R function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547306/generate-multiple-graphics-from-within-an-r-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read Faq 7.22:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f

You need to print() your ggplot or lattice plots.

Comment: That did the trick, I enclosed changed the `ggplot(...)...` to `print(ggplot(...)...)` and it worked.

Comment: Everyone working with lattice or ggplot looses at least half a day to the old "why doesn't my plot plot" problem :).

Comment: I remember that Superguru Douglas Bates called Deepayan in the middle of the night when the latter was in India on the same subject.