# Create multiple plots (one plot for each column) in a data frame using 'for' loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, plot, multiple-columns

I want to make multiple histogram plots (one for each column) in a data frame using a 'for' loop in R. The sample data (df) looks like as follows.

[image]

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(Hockey = c(0.03, 0.032, 0.07, 0.033, 0.076, 0.064
), Cricket = c(0.003, 0.004, 0.009, 0.004, 0.009, 0.008), Tennis = c(0.004, 
0.006, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.011), Badminton = c(27.1, 28.7, 
28.7, 29.4, 31, 33.6), Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("TeamA", "TeamB", "TeamC"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("Participant1", 
"Participant2", "Participant3", "Participant4", "Participant5", 
"Participant6"), class = "data.frame")
```

I have already done my online search and I managed to get this code. For each column, I want to make multiple histograms based on 'Groups'. This works for me when I do it without a 'for' loop and for one single column. However, when I try to do it using a 'for' loop all at ones for all columns in 'one single pdf', then the pdf file does get generated without any errors. But it does not produce any plots. Can anyone help me with knowing as to what I might be missing in the code? I just want to make this automated because I have much more than these 4 variables to make such plots for.

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(doBy)
setwd("C:\\Path\\")

df <- read.table("Histograms_Example.txt", header=T)
pdf(file=paste0("one.pdf"))
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))

loop.vector <- names(df)[1:4]
for (i in loop.vector) {
x <- df[,i]
mu <- summaryBy(x ~ Groups, data = df, 
          FUN = list(median), na.rm = TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, color=Groups, fill=Groups)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity", alpha=0.5)+ 
geom_density(alpha=0.6)+
geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=x.median, color=Groups),
           linetype="dashed")+
scale_color_grey()+
scale_fill_grey() +
labs(title="Weight histogram plot",x=paste("",x), y = "Density")+
theme_classic()
}
dev.off()
```

Thanking you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some of your data using `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Sure, I have done that. This is just an example data as shown in the image. At this point they are not normally distributed, but just as a dummy to help myself get through the working of the pdf output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate multiple graphics from within an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547306/generate-multiple-graphics-from-within-an-r-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly print the ggplot object within the for loop:

1. Assign the plot to an object: `p = ggplot(...)`
2. Print the object: `print(p)`

Comment: This solves it and helps me understand too. Thank you so much.